# Estimation of standard deviation.

Tags: statistics

Let $\overline X$ be a mean of any population, $\overline Y$  as well. 
Now, $ \Theta$  is any unbiased parameter, $X,Y$ are independent.
I don't understand a following formula:

$\overline \Theta$ is an estimator of $\Theta$, $\overline \Theta = \overline X - \overline Y$

$$ \sigma( \overline \Theta ) =(*) \sqrt{Var(\overline X - \overline Y )} = (**) \sqrt{Var(\overline X) + Var(\overline Y) } $$
I don't understand (*), and (**).
Please explain me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is just a definition of $\sigma$. Second step is explained by independece of random variables. If we have two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ then $Var(\alpha\cdot X+ \beta\cdot Y) = \alpha^2\cdot Var(X)+ \beta^2\cdot Var(Y)$ for any $\alpha, \beta$.